# How to make a persistent class with foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table, and I have to write the classes with JPA Annotations for persistent. The tables are this:

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `player` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `team_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(16536) NOT NULL,
    `position` varchar(16536) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `team_id` (`team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I tried this, but I think it's incomplete. It's something missing? It's correct what I wrote?

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    long teamId;
    String name;
    String position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team has more players. This is 1:N relation. In JPA you create it using [@OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) anotation:

```
@Entity
@Table("team")
public class Team {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table("player")
public class Player {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn("team_id")
    Team team;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String position;
}
```

For id use object type Long. At persist time entity id is null. After persist, DB will assign value to it.

Comment: If it helped mark answer as correct, this is how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

JPA will map the foreign entity by it's class.

Try the following:

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    Team teamId;
    String name;
    String position;
}
```